# How can i backup a particular table with table data in SQL server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I want to backup a particular table with table data from a database in SQL Server 2005.
Thanks.

Comment: Where you want to store backup table? In file or in another table?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

easiest way through SSMS
1. Right-click the database (note not the table)

1. Choose Tasks > Generate Scripts
2. In the Choose Objects pane, select the table you want to script
3. In the Set Scripting Options pane, click Advanced.
4. In the Types of Data to Script option, choose Schema and Data. (If you also want indexes, etc. make sure they are also chosen)

read more from http://sqlblog.com/blogs/greg_low/archive/2012/06/28/25981.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
INTO  backup_tab_name 
FROM actual_table_name
```

This will accomplish your requirement